# Android Spinner set default option

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner

Allowing user to edit his|her profile info, a form is built in a fragment, one the form elements is a spinner, this is how I have configured the spinner in layout:

```
<com.skydoves.powerspinner.PowerSpinnerView
        android:id="@+id/gradeSelect"
        style="@style/smallTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="40dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_white_rounded_primaryblue_all_radius_8"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:hint="@string/grade_12"
        app:spinner_arrow_gravity="start"
        app:spinner_arrow_tint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:spinner_divider_color="@color/red"
        app:spinner_divider_show="true"
        app:spinner_divider_size="1dp"
        app:spinner_item_array="@array/grades"
        app:spinner_popup_animation="bounce"
        app:spinner_popup_background="@drawable/button_blue2_rounded_blue2_all_radius_12"
        app:spinner_popup_elevation="140dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/grade"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/okBtn"/>
```

the PowerSpinnerView is used in this project as it needed to be themed. the elements get shown in form and we can store the value set in spinner through spinner adapter, the problem we are faced now is we cant figure it out how to set old user selection as spinner's default option when form gets displayed.

Comment: ```powerSpinnerView.selectItemByIndex(4)``` add this line 
4 means selected  your item index

Comment: app:spinner_preference_name="item_name"